# Spectral Hashing of images for matching with hamming distance

Tags: python, database, computer-vision

I am looking for a Python implementation of a Spectral Hashing or Semantic Hashing algorithm for images. Which works on hamming distances so that I can easily store it in a database like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

I have also read about using a GIST to determine descriptors of a image and then using Spectral Hashing, LSH or a RBM. However, I don't know how to implement something like this in Python.

So far I have found some LSH code in Python, but I don't know if it generates a binary hash for Hamming distances.

I have tried pHashing, however that doesn't work nicely for object recognition in images.

I don't want a large arrays of keypoint descriptors where you have to calculate the euclidean distance, which is slow or need special data structures to match to other images.

Thanks

Comment: If anyone is still looking for the python implementation of hashing algorithms, the following repository may help them:
https://github.com/zavareh89/unsupervised-hashing

Answer (score 1):

You can try this package: https://github.com/wanji/hdidx.
It also implements the Product Quantization algorithm proposed by Herve Jegou :)